# r convert number saved as char in tibble to double NA introduced

Tags: r, time-series, tibble

I'd like to convert the relevant columns in the following tibble to numeric (double precision):

```
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  Date       Open      High       Low      Close   Shares
  <chr>      <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>   <chr> 
1 16.04.2021 53,64     54,12     53,64     54,12   50    
2 15.04.2021 53,19     53,19     53,19     53,19   -     
3 14.04.2021 53,29     53,29     53,29     53,29   -     
4 13.04.2021 52,86     52,86     52,86     52,86   -     
5 12.04.2021 53,17     53,17     53,17     53,17   -     
6 09.04.2021 53,18     53,18     53,18     53,18   -
```

However, if I apply `as.numeric` to the relevant columns, `NA` would be introduced.

What is the most efficient way to convert the entries in the relevant columns to `double` without generating the `NA`s?

Reproducible sample data:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~Date,       ~Open,      ~High,       ~Low,      ~Close,   ~Shares,
 "16.04.2021",  "53,64",     "54,12",     "53,64",     "54,12",   50,    
 "15.04.2021",  "53,19",     "53,19",     "53,19",     "53,19",   NA,     
 "14.04.2021",  "53,29",     "53,29",     "53,29",     "53,29",   NA,     
 "13.04.2021",  "52,86",     "52,86",     "52,86",     "52,86",   NA,     
 "12.04.2021",  "53,17",     "53,17",     "53,17",     "53,17",   NA,     
 "09.04.2021",  "53,18",     "53,18",     "53,18",     "53,18",   NA 
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace comma with a dot and convert to numeric. Use `lapply` to apply the function to multiple columns.

```
df[2:5] <- lapply(df[2:5], function(x) as.numeric(sub(',', '.', x)))
```

Using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(Open:Close, ~parse_number(., locale = locale(decimal_mark = ","))))
```

Comment: I've never been aware of the `locale` function that we can control the decimal mark with, in one act. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

That reason you can't turn them into numeric values are `,` as decimal separator instead of `.`. So you can use the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(Open:Close, ~ str_replace(., ",", "\\.")),
         across(Open:Close, as.numeric))

# A tibble: 6 x 6
  Date        Open  High   Low Close Shares
  <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 16.04.2021  53.6  54.1  53.6  54.1     50
2 15.04.2021  53.2  53.2  53.2  53.2     NA
3 14.04.2021  53.3  53.3  53.3  53.3     NA
4 13.04.2021  52.9  52.9  52.9  52.9     NA
5 12.04.2021  53.2  53.2  53.2  53.2     NA
6 09.04.2021  53.2  53.2  53.2  53.2     NA
```

Answer (score 2):

First escape the "." in your regular expression.

Second replace the commas with a "." before you can convert to numeric

```
df  %>% 
  mutate(across(2:5, ~as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", gsub("\\.", "", .)))))
```

Output:

```
  Date        Open  High   Low Close Shares
  <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
1 16.04.2021  53.6  54.1  53.6  54.1 50    
2 15.04.2021  53.2  53.2  53.2  53.2 -     
3 14.04.2021  53.3  53.3  53.3  53.3 -     
4 13.04.2021  52.9  52.9  52.9  52.9 -     
5 12.04.2021  53.2  53.2  53.2  53.2 -     
6 09.04.2021  53.2  53.2  53.2  53.2 -
```

Comment: Always a pleasure.